# How to edit photo directly taken from camera and upload it on iphone?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, file-upload, crop

I have a simple upload input on my website `<input type="file" onchange="this.submit();">`. When I press it, iphone asks me if I want to take a new photo or select photo from gallery. I choose take a new photo. After taking it, I would need to have possibility to `crop` it or add `annotation` (make a line, circle or any other shape on photo) and this edited photo should be uploaded to server. Problem is that features for cropping and so on are only when I take a photo, save it to gallery and upload it from there.

Is there a way how to have these features while taking a new photo without saving it into gallery? I am wondering about iphone only.

If it is not possible, is there a way how to crop and add annotation after photo is uploaded by any PHP library?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Upload the photo to your server and then delete it after the required executions are completed.

For Dealing With Images & Media, We Use The [PHP GD Library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)